# pandas expanding with custom function for aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, apply

I am trying to understand why does this code throws an error. Even if the first 30 rows after `expanding` is of `np.nan` that still should allow numeric operations. Why does it fail? How should I fix this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

i = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2000-06-01', freq='D')
x = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,10, (len(i), 3)), index = i, columns = list('abc'))
# this works
# x.expanding(min_periods=30).corr()
# this doesn't. Why? Is it because of nans? Isn't np.nan a float
x.expanding(min_periods=30).aggregate(lambda t: t.corr().stack().loc[[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c')], :])
# this fails too
# x.expanding(min_periods=30).aggregate(lambda t: t+1)
```

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

I can generate the desire output by this code:

```
y = x.expanding(min_periods=30).corr()
y.index.names = ['dates', 'letters']
y.columns.name = 'cols'
y=y.stack()
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a','b'), ('a','c')], names = ['letters', 'cols'])
y.to_frame().join(pd.DataFrame(index=mi), on=['letters', 'cols'], how='inner')
```

Comment: Your usage of `aggregate` is completely wrong. Fixing errors is useless, so create desired output you want. and need a minimal and reproducible example, `i = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2000-01-05', freq='D'); x = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,10, (len(i), 3)), index = i, columns = list('abc'))` if you provide desired output of this input(min_periods=2) your problem will be solved

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
out = (x.rename_axis("dates").expanding(min_periods=30).corr().xs("a", level=1)
           [["b", "c"]].dropna().melt(var_name="cols", ignore_index=False)
           .set_index("cols", append=True)
)
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

                    value
dates      cols          
2000-01-30 b    -0.210288
2000-01-31 b    -0.223870
2000-02-01 b    -0.224411
2000-02-02 b    -0.156831
2000-02-03 b    -0.164199
...                   ...
2000-05-28 c     0.022239
2000-05-29 c     0.027344
2000-05-30 c     0.014873
2000-05-31 c     0.014310
2000-06-01 c     0.024398

[248 rows x 1 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the code fails when using the expanding() method with the aggregate() function is due to the presence of NaN values in the first 29 rows, as you suspected.

When using aggregate() with the expanding() method, Pandas first tries to create a DataFrame containing all the values in the window. Since there are NaN values in the first 29 rows, the aggregation function :

```
(lambda t: t.corr().stack().loc[[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c')], :]
```

in this case is applied to a DataFrame that contains NaN values. This causes the error.

The presence of NaN values can cause unexpected results when performing mathematical operations or aggregation functions, which is why it's a good idea to handle them explicitly in your code.

To fix this issue, you can use the dropna() method to remove rows containing NaN values before performing the aggregation:

```
x.expanding(min_periods=30).apply(lambda t:t.dropna().corr().stack().loc[[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c')], :])
```

Here, we use the 'apply()' method instead of 'aggregate()' and first remove the rows containing NaN values by calling'dropna()' on the DataFrame 't' passed to the lambda function. Then we compute the correlation matrix and stack the result as before.

Comment: But this fails too.